# Bootloader location and boot procedures when dual booting with Windows in BIOS/MBR mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently switched back to a G31 board which only supports BIOS firmware, and am wondering what would happen if I try a Windows dual boot.

[image: Image from Wikipedia]
*(note that we will be talking about the situation described in **Example 1**)*

Both Windows and Ubuntu installer align 1MiB offset before the first partition.

### Linux first

Ubuntu will install `boot.img` on the 446-byte MBR bootstrap code area, and `core.img` right after the MBR partition table. What would happen if Windows is installed after that? I suspect it will likely overwrite the `boot.img` area, and probably replace `core.img` with its own bootloader as well. Or maybe it just boot straight from the bootstrap area to its bootloader which resides somewhere on `C:\Windows`. I don't know how the Windows Boot Manager works.

### Windows first

Windows will leaves its 446-byte bootstrap code inside MBR, which point to its actual bootloader somewhere on the disk (it could be straight to `C:\Windows`, but could be 3 stages like GRUB 2, I don't know). If I install Ubuntu afterward, GRUB 2 shall overwrite the bootstrap area with `boot.img`. What I am confused here is the location where it puts `core.img` to avoid conflict with Windows Boot Manager. According to [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#BIOS-installation), `core.img` can be put on a normal file system rather than left hidden inside unpartition space.

---

Can someone shed some light on this? I really want to know how it works, to be able to backup and manage both OSes.

Comment: ok things are so, soo much simpler in reality, especially with newer techs like BIOS. in this case it will be super SUPER easy. all you have to do is create your windows10 install medium. install windows. take the whole drive! use your windows and run rufus to create your ubuntu installer USB key (make sure to select "GPT" and "BIOS"). Don't format to free space for ubuntu! don't! install ubuntu, in the menu that shows up select "install allongside windows" (sometimes it says "install allongside bootloader") and then use the slider to determine how much space ubuntu will "steal" from windows.

Comment: just don't try to attempt installing linux first. https://www.google.com/search?q=which+should+i+install+first+windows+or+linux&oq=which+should+i+install+first+windows+or+linux&aqs=chrome..69i57.12675j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @tatsu Then what happens when Microsoft release a new version and I decide to wipe the whole Windows partition to perform a clean installation?

Comment: you just do the same afterwards with ubuntu. that's what I do. i never keep data, media, games or documents on the SSD/nvme's I install my OSes to anyways, I keep them on a big HDD. I'm always prepared for a reinstall because that's honestly the best most convenient way. Yes this adds an extra step. that being said let's get realistic for a second here. windows is not releasing a new windows not now not ever. 10 marks the ultimate/last version of windows. they now have a full linux kernel in windows 10 and they can hotswap core components just like linux, so they don't need further versions.

Comment: just updates. and ubuntu is pretty much the same. I've gone from 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04 just via upgrades (terminal) which I have to say is a little new for me but quite convenient. so realistically you'd just run updates in windows and then yeah you could do a full fresh install of ubuntu for the new version; and that would work fine since that's still "windows first". however if you're feeling lazy you could just do an upgrade for ubuntu and that's that. :D

Comment: I'll make a full answer with this, sound good?

Comment: @tatsu I was terribly busy in the last 2 weeks and forgot to answer. I actually tested myself. I tried to `dd` zeroes to almost every suspect location, which is quite time consuming, but now I know how it works. Basically Windows boots up using its MBR bootstrap code, which in turns calls the VBR bootstrap of the active partition, then leaves the remaining job to `bootmgr`. It only conflicts with `boot.img` of GRUB2, but can be easily restored by `dd` a backup copy, or just by `bootrect.exe /FixMbr`.

Comment: I mean yeah if you want to but as i said there's no cause for you to be reinstalling windows anyhow so why not just install ubuntu first and windows on top?